# Expected number of rolls to cover all stops

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization, combinations

Suppose there is a board game, the map is a circle with 70 stops on it. The game uses a 6 faces fair die. Assume there is only 1 player, every time the player rolls a die, s/he will move counter clockwise based on the number shows on the die.

What is the expected number of rolls to get on every stop at least once on the map?

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Suggestion: Imagine a probability of the player being in position $i$ at time $n$: $P_i^n$ (vector of 70 components for each time) and each roll disperses this probability with a discrete convolution with $(0,1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6,0,0,0,0,\ldots)$. to get $P_i^{n+1}$. This part cen be simplified with fourier transform (though probably not in closed form). Then you have to express probability of not having landed on any of them yet (you'll have to take into account all previous times including the current one). This will be a function of $n$, then you can take expected value of $n$.

Comment: For reference, simulation puts the average at $\approx335.8$ if you don't count the initial position until the first return.